# Input data type changed after training the model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

My trained model accepts images of int32 datatype. However, my upstream sends float32 data. Do I have to convert the training images to float32 and train the model again? My code looks something like this:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = dataset.load_data()
print(x_train.dtype)
# 'int32'
```

Comment: Either convert your data to int32 or retrain your model using float32, unless you can deal with the loss of extra data, but that can have significant, and unpredictable affects on model performance.

Comment: You can try training the model with your existing data and let us know with full traceback error in case it shows any error.